# Composable by-member comparison

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, template, constrained-templates

## Motivation

Quite often, I find myself creating types that must be compared memberwise.  For example, consider this simple `Person`:

```
#include <string>

struct Person
{
    // Pretend that the falsehoods programmers believe about names are
    // all actually true.
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string birthdate;  // e.g. "1985-07-03"
};
```

Suppose we want these to sort by last name, tie-breaking with first name, and then by age.  The standard idiom is to create a tuple, and compare that:

```
bool operator<(const Person& other) const {
    return std::tie(last_name, first_name, other.birthdate)
        <  std::tie(other.last_name, other.first_name, birthdate)
}
```

This is a bit tedious and error-prone - it's easy to mess up the swapping of `birthdate` and `other.birthdate`, for example.

So I've created a builder for memberwise comparison.  It's easy to use: start with an empty comparator and add or subtract pointers to member fields or functions.  Adding will append an *ascending* ordering, and subtracting will append a *descending* ordering:

```
std::sort(std::begin(people), std::end(people),
          sorting::compare{} + &Person::last_name + &Person::first_name
                             - &Person::birthdate);
```

---

## The code

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

namespace sorting {

    namespace implementation {

        template<typename T>
        concept bool Comparator = requires {
            typename T::comparable_type;
        };

        template<Comparator Sort>
        struct reverse {
            using comparable_type = typename Sort::comparable_type;
            const Sort sort;

            bool operator()(const comparable_type& a,
                            const comparable_type& b) const
            {
                return sort(b, a);
            }

            auto&& operator-() && { return sort; }
        };

        template<Comparator First, Comparator Second>
        struct sequence {
            using comparable_type = typename First::comparable_type;
            const First first;
            const Second second;

            bool operator()(const comparable_type& a,
                            const comparable_type& b) const
            {
                return first(a, b) || !first(b,a) && second(a, b);
            }

            sequence operator-() const { return {-first, -second}; }
        };

        template<typename T, typename V>
        struct by_member
        {
            using comparable_type = T;
            V T::*const member;

            bool operator()(const comparable_type& a,
                            const comparable_type& b) const
            {
                return std::invoke(member, a) < std::invoke(member, b);
            }

            auto operator-() const { return reverse<by_member>{*this}; }
        };

        template<typename T, typename V>
        constexpr auto sort_by(V T::*m) { return by_member<T,V>{m}; }
        template<Comparator T>
        constexpr const T& sort_by(const T& t) { return t; }

        // Functions for combining comparators
        template<Comparator A, Comparator B>
        requires std::is_same_v<typename A::comparable_type,
                                typename B::comparable_type>
        constexpr auto operator+(const A& a, const B& b) -> sequence<A, B>
        {
            return { a, b };
        }

        template<Comparator A, Comparator B>
        requires !std::is_same_v<typename A::comparable_type,
                                 typename B::comparable_type>
        constexpr auto operator+(const A& a, const B& b) = delete;

        template<typename A, typename B>
        constexpr auto operator+(const A& a, const B& b)
        {
            return sort_by(a) + sort_by(b);
        }

        template<typename A, typename B>
        constexpr auto operator-(const A& a, const B& b)
        {
            return sort_by(a) + -sort_by(b);
        }

        // Empty object that's a public starting point for combining comparers.
        // This allows ADL to find all the necessary implementation classes.
        struct compare
        {
            template<typename T>
            auto operator+(T&& t) { return sort_by(t); }
            template<typename T>
            auto operator-(T&& t) { return -sort_by(t); }
        };
    }

    // Here's the entirety of the public interface:

    using implementation::compare;
}
```

// Test program:

```
#include <string>

struct Person
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string birthdate;

    static auto const& default_compare() {
        static auto const default_compare
            = sorting::compare{} + &Person::last_name
                                 + &Person::first_name - &Person::birthdate;
        return default_compare;
    }

    bool operator<(const Person& other) const {
        return default_compare()(*this, other);
    }
};

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person (&people)[N])
{
    for (auto p: people)
        os << "  " << p.first_name << ' ' << p.last_name << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Person people[] = {
        { "Emmett",    "Brown", "1925-07-03" },
        { "Marty",     "McFly", "1968-07-03" },
        { "Jennifer", "Parker", "1968-07-03" },
        { "George",    "McFly", "1938-07-03" },
        { "Lorraine",  "McFly", "1938-04-03" },
        { "Biff",     "Tannen", "1938-07-03" },
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(people), std::end(people));
    std::clog << "Default order:\n"
              << people << "\n";

    std::sort(std::begin(people), std::end(people),
              sorting::compare{} - &Person::birthdate
                  + Person::default_compare());
    std::clog << "Youngest first:\n"
              << people << "\n";

    std::sort(std::begin(people), std::end(people),
              sorting::compare{} + &Person::last_name
                  + &Person::birthdate + &Person::first_name);
    std::clog << "By family, then birthdate:\n"
              << people;
}
```

Because I use C++ Concepts Lite, that will need to be enabled in your compiler, if you're reading this before that is standard.  I used `g++ -std=c++17 -fconcepts`, but newer standards should work, too.

---

## Concerns

Obviously I'd like to make my code better in any way.

I did attempt to change the `sequence` type to a variadic template.  Although I was successful in constructing these, I couldn't work out how to call the next function inside `operator()`.  And I doubt that it's any better for compilation or for the generated code.  But it might improve the error messages when the programmer makes a mistake.

Comment: Looks interesting -- I look forward to reviewing this later.

Comment: Interesting, but I fear inefficient...

Comment: @Deduplicator, if you can identify places that are inefficient (do you mean at run-time, or during compilation?), please do write an answer, however short.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, the relative inefficiency is caused by having and using data (member-pointers) instead of only code. Of course, if it is all inlined, that will disappear.

Comment: Fortunately we will have `auto operator<=>(const C&, const C&) = default;` in C++20 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to include `<type_traits>`.

```
auto&& operator-() && { return sort; }
```

The `&&` qualification seems questionable, and the decision to return an lvalue reference from a `&&` qualified function even more so.

```
sequence operator-() const { return {-first, -second}; }
```

This function appears to have been untested. Based on what you have here, the chance that `-first` has the same type as `first` seems to be vanishingly low.

> ```
>     template<Comparator A, Comparator B>
>     requires std::is_same_v<typename A::comparable_type,
>                             typename B::comparable_type>
>     constexpr auto operator+(const A& a, const B& b) -> sequence<A, B>
> ```

Pinning down to a single common `comparable_type` seems unnecessary, not the least because the type of member pointers can be surprising in the presence of inheritance:

```
struct MiddleNamedPerson : Person { std::string middle_name; };
```

`&MiddleNamedPerson::first_name` is of the type `std::string Person::*`, while `&MiddleNamedPerson::middle_name` is of the type `std::string MiddleNamedPerson::*`, so attempts to compose them will fail under your scheme.

Here's an (untested) sketch of variadic `sequence`:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct sequence {
    // other stuff
    const std::tuple<Ts...> tup;
    template<class T, class U>
    bool operator()(const T& t, const U& u) const {
        return std::apply([&](const auto&... comps) {
            bool result = false, stop = false;
            ((stop || (comps(t, u) ? stop = true, result = true :
                       comps(u, t) ? stop = true, result = false : false )),
              ...);
            return result;
        }, tup);
     }
};
```

And another variant that's perhaps easier to follow:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct sequence {
    // other stuff
    const std::tuple<Ts...> tup;

    template<std::size_t N> 
    using size_constant = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;

    template<class T, class U>
    bool operator()(const T& t, const U& u) const {
        return compare(t, u, size_constant<0>());
    }
    template<class T, class U, std::size_t N>
    bool compare(const T& t, const U& u, size_constant<N>) const {
       if(std::get<N>(tup)(t, u)) return true;
       if(std::get<N>(tup)(u, t)) return false;
       return compare(t, u, size_constant<N+1>());
    }
    template<class T, class U>
    bool compare(const T& t, const U& u, 
                 size_constant<sizeof...(Ts)>) const {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, the sequence `-` operator missed testing.  It was just supposed to be an optimization, and I don't think it's a worthwhile one.  It won't get used unless you use the class non-idiomatically, so not worth keeping.  Other points all good - though I'll have to do some thinking about whether/how to keep `comparable_type`.  I did start off with it in the `compare{}` (factory) object, to dictate what it could combine with.  Thanks for the good advice!